# ResourceLoader returns wrong language inside ViewModel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, localization, uwp

I'm making a UWP application with Template10, and I currently have this folder structure inside my project for localization:

```
Localization
|_en
|  |_Resources.resw
|_it-IT
   |_Resources.resw
```

The default app language is en, and my current culture is it-IT.
The resource files are correct and the behavior is consistent through the app, showing always the Italian version first.

I'm using the ResourceLoader class inside View's code behind just fine, but as long as I use it inside the ViewModel it always returns the English localization, even if it doesn't exist (= empty string, although it exists in Italian file).

I'm using it inside the VM is because I'm creating a new Character and giving it a default name ("No name"), as a placeholder for the user, binding the name inside the View.

This is the code I use:

```cs
public class CharacterManagerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Character Character { get; set; }
    private ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader();

    public override async void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            //Creating a default empty character
            Character = new Character();
            Character.Name = loader.GetString("NewCharacterName");
        }
        else
        {
            //Loading from the Model
        }
    }
}
```

As I call the GetString() method, the current culture is it-IT but somehow the framework ignores it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what's important is the current culture when you create the ResourceLoader, not the current culture when you call GetString. You should use an explicit constructor for your viewmodel and make sure the culture is correct. If that doesn't work, you can try constructing your ResourceLoader using `ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView()`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.
Before posting this, I tried to move the ResourceLoader initialization inside the OnNavigatedTo event, but it's the same.

I also tried your suggestion, but that doesn't work too. It still uses the default language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the origin of my problem:
inside the Model, in a method I cut in the code for simplicity, I load some data for the "Character" object from XML files included in the app.

Inside that method I change the culture to InvariantCulture to ensure the format is independent from the user's one.
At the end of that method, I change it back to user's culture but somewhat something goes wrong.

The issue happens after I make the double swap, and it is reflected afterwards to the entire software, even for localized strings from the View.

The issue is not dependent to the ViewModel, I'll work on the issue and if I cannot find anything I'll post a new question.